# Best Practise to use access controll with RBAC Yii 2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am using RBAC control in my app, usually i'am using `Yii::$app->user->can('permission')`. 
But i have problems, when i'm combining Access Control with RBAC it's not working. An e.g my code:

```
public function behaviors() {
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'ruleConfig' => [
                'class' => AccessRule::className(),
            ],
            'only' => ['test', 'view', 'index', 'ajaxdatevehicle', 'price_list', 'ajax_suggest_area', 'view-admin'],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['test', 'view', 'index', 'ajaxdatevehicle', 'price_list', 'ajax_suggest_area', 'view-admin'],
                    'allow' => false,
                    'roles' => [
                        '?',
                    ],
                ],
                [
                    'actions' => ['test', 'view', 'index', 'ajaxdatevehicle', 'price_list', 'ajax_suggest_area', 'view-admin'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => [
                        '@',
                    ],
                ],
                [
                    'actions' => ['index'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['?'],
                ],
                [
                    // This is the problem
                    'actions' => ['view'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => [
                        '?',
                        User::ROLE_CUSTOMER,
                        Yii::$app->user->can('customer'),
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'delete' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

I want the page 'view' to be accesses by customer only, so how to solve this problem?.

or what is the best practise to do this?.

Thanks

Comment: Just my opinion, but I'm not sure if going on every controller and adding behaviors like this would be the best way. It looks a litle messy and it's not fast to change everything when need to. I would recommend you check this module https://github.com/mdmsoft/yii2-admin. If you dont want to use it (and want to build your own rbac system) you can test it and see how it works. You dont have to make any edition in your controllers, just configure everything right and add the permissions correctly in your db.

Answer (score 1):

This way

```
   [
         // This is the problem
         'actions' => ['view'],
         'allow' => true,
         'roles' => ['customer'],
   ],
```